# How can I set Websocket Origin Header in react-native?

Tags: ajax, react-native, websocket, webrtc, siteorigin

I want to change Origin Header of the websocket handshake in react native.

like this

```
var ws = new WebSocket(
    'http://localhost/auth',
    [],
    {
        'headers': {
            'Origin': "https://secret-host.com"
        }
    }
);
```

I also tried react-native ios websocket library directly.

from

```
CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, CFSTR("Origin"), (__bridge CFStringRef)_url.RCTSR_origin);
```

to

```
CFHTTPMessageSetHeaderFieldValue(request, CFSTR("Origin"), CFSTR("https://secret-host.com"));
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTSRWebSocket.m#L468

But it can't work.

Does anyone know how to change it? I need this for using skyway(WebRTC) in react-native.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed approach should actually work in React Native 0.68.* and higher:

```
var ws = new WebSocket(
    'http://localhost/auth',
    undefined,
    {
        headers: {
            Origin: 'https://secret-host.com',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ***'
        }
    }
);
```

The caveat is that **it always adds an origin header**, so you cannot remove it without patching RN itself (which is doable using [patch-package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/patch-package)). This is the code you were referring to - it always generates a default `Origin:` header. You can set it to `Origin: ""` but it will still be sent which may not be good enough for your server.

[On later lines in the linked RN code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTSRWebSocket.m#L474), it's being overwritten by your custom JS value in an "enumeration"/loop which is why your code should work.

To check if the header is being set, you can add a breakpoint in that file you linked on line 483 (`[self _readHTTPHeader];`) in Xcode and when the socket connects, add a watch for the following code:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:message encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then right click the watched value and click "Print description":
[image]

You should see the actual output of the HTTP request, which will be something like this:

```
GET /auth
Host: localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Key: eHh4YWJjZGVmZ2hpamts
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: https://secret-host.com
Connection: Upgrade
```